# remove a div element when clicking anywhere else than that div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing trouble in removing a div element that I have created with JavaScript. I call this function onclick  element.

```
function makediv(){
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        $(div).attr('id','md');
        $(div).css({"left":e.pageX,"top":e.pageY });
        $("body").append(div);
    }
```

And here how I'am trying to remove when I click somewhere else than that div.
before I click somewhere else the div even showed up it just deleted at the moment it created.

```
window.onclick = function(event)
    {           
        dl=$('#md');
        if(event.target!=dl)
            dl.remove();
    }
```

I have also tried this one.

```
window.onclick = function(event)
    {
        if($('#md').length!=0){

        dl=$('#md');
        if(event.target!=dl)
            dl.remove();
        }
    }
```

But this code remove div element as it is created.

Comment: can you post your html code

Comment: "But this code remove div element as it is created." what do you mean ?

Comment: I want to remove it when I click somewhere else than that div. But this code remove div as it created it even didn't appear.

Comment: Instead of using `if(event.target!=dl)`, try using `if(!$(event.target).is(dl))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` for shorter and easier code.

```js
function makediv() {
  $("body").append("<div id='md'></div>");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  makediv(); /* Call the function to add the div */
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  /* Check if id is mb. If it is not, remove the div */
  if ($(e.target).attr("id") != "md") $("#md").remove();
});
```

```css
#md {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would consider creating an absolute-positioned-fullscreen-transparent div in behind the red one and adding the event to it instead of the whole page elements

Comment: Thanks I think its best solution at all.

Comment: Happy to help @AdeelApple